# Currency is coming as Standard field in every custom object

Tags: currency

I have multiple currencies in my org. My Advanced Currency Management is not enabled. Now when I am creating any custom object, I can see that Currency is coming as Standard field on every object automatically. And due to that while creating a new record of that object, I have to choose currency always. (I can definitely remove currency from page layout though). But what I am not getting is that why currency is coming as Standard field automatically to every custom object? Any idea guys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you have multi-currency on in the org, this causes the field to be added to all the objects. See the [implications of enabling multi-currency](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_enable_multicurrency_implications.htm&language=en_US).

> Upon enablement, all existing records are stamped with a default
>   currency code that you provide in your enablement request. For
>   example, if your organization contains records using USD and EUR, you
>   need to switch them all to the same default currency prior to
>   enablement. Support for this type of conversion is also available as a
>   salesforce.com paid implementation service.

Advanced currency management controls dated exchange rates, it has nothing to do with the currency field.